# Ошибка: "Исключение не обработано" в конструкторе класса

Tags: c++, исключения, шаблоны-с++, конструктор

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//2nd exercise
template <typename T, typename U> 
vector<T> multi(vector<T> vt, vector<U> vu) {
    vector<T> rv;
    for (int i = 0; i < vt.size(); i++) rv.push_back(vt[i] * vu[i]);

    return rv;
}


//5th exercise
class Int {
public:
    Int(int v) : value(v) {}
    Int() : value(0) {}

    Int& operator= (Int& i1);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, const Int& i1);
    friend const Int operator+ (const Int& i1, const Int& i2);
    friend const Int operator- (const Int& i1, const Int& i2);
    friend const Int operator* (const Int& i1, const Int& i2);
    friend const Int operator/ (const Int& i1, const Int& i2);
private:
    int value;
};

Int& Int::operator= (Int& i1) {
    this->value = i1.value;
    return *this;
}

ostream&  operator<< (ostream& s, const Int& i1) {
    s << i1.value;
    return s;
}
```

Функция main:

```
int main() {
    Int a{ 5 };

    cout << a;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: Привидите пожалуйста весь код.

Comment: Добавил. Проблема в перегрузке оператора побитового сдвига: если его не использовать - ошибки нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `explicit` к конструктору:

`explicit Int(int v) : value(v) {}`

Возможно, компилятор в `operator<<` пытается неявно сконвертировать `int` в `Int` и вызывает сам себя рекурсивно.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тексту сообщения об ошибке, у вас переполнился стек. То есть ошибка не в самом классе, а в том, что для создаваемого автоматического объекта нет места в стеке. Такое может быть, например, при неосторожных играх с рекурсией. Или при злоупотреблениями автоматическими объектами большого размера.

Однако, по тому коду, который Вы привели, ничего такого не заметно. Кроме того, он несколько отличается от скриншота (там не видно конструктора по умолчанию). Приведите тот код, на котором реально валится.

Comment: В последнем варианте та же проблема.

Comment: Странно, причин для переполнения стека в коде нет. При чем тут оператор << тоже не понятно. Ибо внутри него объекты класса Int не создаются.

Comment: И я в недоумении. Странно как-то, но то ,что без << код работает - факт. Проверил несколько раз

Comment: Я у себя собрал и запустил (без шаблона наверху - но он нигде не используется). Как и ожидал, все выполнилось без проблем. А что за среда у Вас?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017. Попробовал без шаблона, все ровно не работает.